# Promtheus federation ignoring/dropping # HELP line from metrics

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, federation

Hey guys I faced some issues with exposing metrics to /federate endpoint by Prometheus

I see that for all metrics it drops # HELP lines from each metric. Only # TYPE stays.
Tried to search on documentation and forums can't find any boolean answer like "Prometheus Federation by default drops # HELP line and leaves only # TYPE and the metric"

Someone may be faced it in the past and have some knowledge to share?

Configuration is not really affecting here AFAIK since even **scraping** K8s endpoints with just Kubernetes-pods job without any drops/replacements but providing federate="yes" and then in federation endpoint, there are no # HELP lines, they just dropped by default.

In actual target for pods **scraped** by Prometheus to /metrics or /monitoring endpoint # HELP is persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prometheus [/federate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) endpoint is intended to be consumed by other Prometheus instances and so it exposes only what's strictly needed by another Prometheus instance. While the `# TYPE` line is essential because it defines the type of the metric, the `# HELP` line apparently isn't regarded as essential because there's not done much with it inside Prometheus.

See for example [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/use-prometheus-help-text-in-panel-description-or-metric-legend/11504/2):

> The HELP text in Prometheus’ exposition format was invented with the intent of creating functionality later.

Currently, Prometheus provides a [metadata API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-metric-metadata) that allows to query the `# HELP` text of a metric. But that's about all Prometheus does with the `# HELP` text internally, it's not interpreted in any other ways.

So, in summary, Prometheus currently doesn't expose the `# HELP` line on its federation endpoint because it regards it as non-essential.

However, this might change in the future as more functionality is added. If you have a specific use case, you can always raise a feature request in this area.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for sharing the info!
Yeah saw this community link with a query on metadata
https://community.grafana.com/t/use-prometheus-help-text-in-panel-description-or-metric-legend/11504/2